# How do I reload ZSH config files without replacing the current shell?

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh, zshrc

How do I tell ZSH to reload itself, as if it's a freshly invoked shell, but without losing the history?

The context for this is that I've spent a long time building my ZSH setup, and I'd hate to lose it if my current machine fails, or the drive gets corrupted, etc.  To this end, I've put all my local ZSH config files in a git repository.  Nothing new so far.

But now I want to add an 'install' script to the repository, to ease the process of installing my setup on a new machine.  Once the files are installed (actually, symlinks created in ${ZDOTDIR-~} that point to the files in the repository), I want the script to reload them, without replacing the current process via exec (and therefore losing the history), and without sourcing the files one-by-one (and risking the possibility that I may load them in the wrong order or miss some other part of the ZSH startup process).

Is there some facility built in to ZSH, or some other way to tell it to reload everything, as if it was a freshly started instance, while preserving the command history?

EDIT:  Hah. Um.. hrm.. of course, I've now wiped out my .zshrc and .zlogin, Though the latter is no great hardship (It just had RVM's setup in it, which is easily recovered).  The former, however, *hurts*.  Anyone who can tell me how to *recover* a .zshrc from a shell that has sourced it gets all my super bonus points.  An answer to the original question will still be marked as accepted, of course.

*I had a problem.  I wrote a shell script.  [Now I have two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)* :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can enable the option `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`. From the manpage:

> INC_APPEND_HISTORY
>
> This options works like APPEND_HISTORY except that new history lines are added to the $HISTFILE incrementally (as soon as they are entered), rather than waiting until the shell exits. The file will still be periodically re-written to trim it when the number of lines grows 20% beyond the value specified by $SAVEHIST (see also the HIST_SAVE_BY_COPY option).

This way you can then do `exec zsh` without losing history.

Comment: This is the closest thing I think is probably possible to what I was trying to do.  Much obliged.

Comment: How can I enable `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`?

Comment: @alper Add `setopt inc_append_history` to your `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 151):

Usually a `source ~/.zshrc` should do it.

Comment: Do `source ~/.zshenv` to reload stuff from that file.

Comment: This doesn't reload aliases on macOS. Use `exec zsh` to launch a new shell instead.

Answer (score 68):

For **oh-my-zsh** users

Here is the way to reload the .zshrc without losing the terminal

```
omz reload
```

Found here: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Cheatsheet

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @ng10 Which version of omz are you using ? did you checked that omz was enabled by default / the terminal app you are using ?

Comment: thank you - my bad. did not notice this was a specific answer for omz

Comment: oddly calling `source` didn't work in my case (changed alias to a function) but this did

Comment: Note that ``omz reload`` is the same as ``exec zsh``.  So if you do not have **oh-my-zsh** installed you can just use``exec zsh`` which is 2 characters shorter BTW.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit older, but you can always add a function to your .zshrc that sources all config files for you.

```
function reload(){
       source ~/.zshrc
       source ~/.zshenv
       ...
   }
```

So all you'd have to do is to `reload` in your shell.

Comment: The order matters. Usually `.zshenv` is read __before__ `.zshrc`.

Comment: If you do this over and over again the shell slowes down

Answer (score 5):

If

```
source .zshrc
```

outputs

> source: no such file or directory: .zshrc,

you should run below command instead

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: you just need to source the full path in that case:
`source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 1):

To respect the `ZDOTDIR`, which should be set by `.zshenv`, use this combination:

```sh
source $HOME/.zshenv && source ${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshrc
```